Why was "how-is-insider-trading-tracked" migrated?
The question
"how is insider trading tracked?", was recently migrated to money.SE.
Why?  

I migrated that question along with this one from the same user. When the answer to his question is simply "Form 4" or "short interest", then it doesn't belong on a quant site. For that matter, those questions would be pretty basic for any site dedicated to professional trading, quant or otherwise.

Thanks. I agree that the question isn't quantitative in nature. Nevertheless, I think migrating is not ideal when answers contain quantitative arguments or useful ideas/links. (I am not arguing about the usefulness of my own answer)

@RYogi Yeah, I was actually hesitant to migrant because you had gotten rep points and I didn't think it was fair to take those away from you. But I couldn't justify migrating only the short-interest question and not the insiders question; that would have been very confusing for the user who asked them. If you sign-up for Money.SE then you'll receive credit for your answer there. (All of my SuperUser answer credit comes from having StackOverflow questions migrated.)

No worries. So far no rep points have been deducted, so no harm done.

Although it is not universally true, generally questions that are finance related but have no quantitative content (such as the question you reference) would be more appropriate to the Personal Finance & Money site.  However, some questions that would be inappropriate on any stack exchange site should be closed here rather than migrated.
As to why was it migrated now, you'll have to ask Chris, but I suspect it was just some overdue clean-up.
